# How to print all the values of a variable outside a loop?

Tags: mysql, loops, go

In this code, I have a function in which I find the users' names. It finds them and prints all the names inside the loop but when I return the `s` variable outside the loop, it prints only the first name. It does not print all the names.

Although I append `s` variable in another variable also but still does not work.

```
type Signup struct {
    Names       string
    Emails     string
}

func FindNames() string {
    db := Connect()
    var s string
    rows, err := db.Query("select names from Signup")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var signup Signup
        err := rows.Scan(&signup.Names)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // s = signup.Names
        // fmt.Println(s)
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%s", signup.Names)
    }
    return s
}
```

Comment: the `Signup` struct doesn't have field `Names`. Where is it from?

Comment: just `s += fmt.Sprintf("%s", signup.Names)`

Comment: @RahmatFathoni You're right. I updated it but it still does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping over stuff it'd make sense to put the results in a list, then do some actions on the results. Or to use a stringbuilder (as it's faster).

Example with list

```golang
type Signup struct {
    Names       string
    Emails     string
}

func FindNames() string {
    db := Connect()
    var s string
    rows, err := db.Query("select names from Signup")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 
    defer rows.Close()

    var names []string

    for rows.Next() {
        var signup Signup
        err := rows.Scan(&signup.Names)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        names = append(names, signup.Names)
    }
    return strings.Join(names, "\n") // newline (\n) character to print multiple lines.
}
```

Stringbuilder

```golang
func FindNames() string {
    db := Connect()
    var s string
    rows, err := db.Query("select names from Signup")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 
    defer rows.Close()

    var sb strings.Builder 

    for rows.Next() {
        var signup Signup
        err := rows.Scan(&signup.Names)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        sb.WriteString(signup.Names)
        sb.WriteRune('\n')
    }
    return sb.String()
}
```

Comment: What if I want to print them line by line?

Comment: Join the strings on a newline character `"\n"`, I'll update the example

Comment: Thank you @pim for providing the solution!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Goodluck programming!